# PHP / Laravel - Execute command every minute for ten minutes

Tags: php, laravel

Apologies if the answer to this is a simple one, but my brain just can't seem to solve this today, I'm hoping someone has had to solve something similar.

So in my database I have various records with timestamps.

In the 10 minutes prior to the timestamp, I'd like to perform an action and store a result in a field.

I'm well aware that this would be easily solved if I just stored these records vertically, as it is I'd like to have the extra fields `tenminutes` `nineminutes` etc in the db - I know this is probably bad DB design but ssshhh, just go with it!

Ok, so my (pseudo)code at the minute read a bit like this:

```
// In a command that is executed every minute using the scheduler....
$current = Carbon::now();

foreach ($things as $thing) {

    if ($thing->thingStartTime->diffInMinutes($current) <= -10) {

               //Get data

               //Update table field `tenminutes`
    }

    if ($thing->thingStartTime->diffInMinutes($current) <= -9) {

               //Get data

               //Update table field `nineminutes`
    }
}
```

Can you see how horrible this will become?

I was thinking along the lines of an associative array, loop through it and have a kind of `'tenminutes' => 10` thing going on?

Or is there a funkier way of using `carbon` I dont know about? Any ideas?

Other info, this is inside a cron job executed every minute! So if thres a way I can use Laravels scheduler to be smart about this, that would be good to know!

Comment: You can create artisan commands and run them with the scheduler

Comment: Hi Aleksei, yeah should mention this is already inside a command being executed every minute

Comment: Is `//Get data` always the same code?

Comment: getData is always the same yeah, the only thing that changes is the time (10, 9, 8 etc) and the name of the database field, i started writing a function but just couldnt get my head round how you'd pass in the time and get it to write to a different db field

Comment: should also mention the field I need to update is on a pivot table. I know the 'easy' way to do this is to create a new record every minute up to the start time, with a pivot table though its a bit trickier

Comment: How about the sleep method? Not sure if it's good practice but something like: `foreach ($things as $thing) { foreach(range(1,10) as $minute) { $dothing; sleep(1000); } }`? Scheduler will for sure be a better option though.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the items and dispatch jobs with different delays?

```
$current = Carbon::now();

foreach ($things as $thing) {
    $delayTime = $current - $thing->thingStartTime;
    $job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->delay($delayTime);

    $this->dispatch($job);
}
```

There is more documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#delayed-jobs).

Comment: This is a pretty nice way of using the queue, but in this example, you'd need to dispatch 10 jobs with  different delays per $thing, right?

Comment: Yes, you would, but it shouldn't be too taxing.

Comment: ah, but inside the job it will need to update a different db field each time, THAT's the tricky bit

Comment: Why do you need to update a database with the field every time? This is 100% able to be calculated if you just put a start time in the database. If start time is 02:00 and current time is 1:55 you know it is `fiveminutes`.

Comment: I would say, you pass the delay time to the job so the job knows which field it is updating that execution.  You can pass anything you want in the job's constructor.

Comment: You could pass the $delayTime to you job, and the spell it in letters using php `NumberFormatter`: `$f = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);`
`$f->format($delayTime); // Spells out "nine" if $delayTime is 9`

Comment: Btw, the solution proposed by @Alex Harris is the best one IMHO

Comment: yeah thought as much, i'll post my implementation soon as its done, cheers guys!